# Ionic Angular maxlength not working in input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, input, apk, maxlength

When I install the APK in my android phone, the input allows me to insert more than 5 characters which I guess it shouldn't be doing since I set maxlength on html and ts.

here's my html:

```
<ion-row id="rowValidCvv"> 
  <ion-input placeholder="Validade" minlength="4" maxlength="5" type="text" class="input" id="inputValid" formControlName='expire_date'></ion-input>
  <ion-input placeholder="CVV" class="input" id="inputCvv" formControlName='card_cvv'></ion-input>
</ion-row>
```

my ts:

```
this.registerCardForm = this.formbuilder.group({
    card_holder_name:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    card_number:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(13)]],
    expire_date:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(5)]],
    card_cvv:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    street_address:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    street_number:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
    state:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    city:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    neighborhood:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    zipcode:[null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(9)]],
    saveCard:[null, [Validators.required]],
  })
```

Here is the print of the apk on phone:

[[image: print of form inputs allowing more than 5 characters]]

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? What version of Android are you using? Are you side loading the APK on the device or are you using an emulator?

Comment: Ionic 6 and Android 10. I am side loading the apk on my device.

Comment: can you show us the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Case is, you use input type="text". If you use type="number" then it validate to 5 characters. But you can't add "/" sign. So you need to add ionic datatime picker to get date and it is easy. Otherwise how you validate day in different months??

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ion-datetime is excellent! I have the habit of not using number type because it keeps people from typing numbers that start with 0. For the input, a solution is using ion simple mask https://github.com/rafaelcorradini/ngx-ion-simple-mask